# Unable to deploy reports to SSRS web browser

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Currently trying to deploy my report to SSRS web browser and I keep getting the error:

> The permissions granted to user '' are insufficient for performing this operation. >

I'm attempting to deploy this from BIDS. I've checked and gave myself administrator/user rights settings in the site security. I'm using Windows 10 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Hm... did you remove the user name from the error message or does it really say `granted to user ''...` ?

Comment: I removed the username.

Comment: Did you try deploying / uploading the reports manually (via web interface)? Did this work? Might help narrowing down the reason...

Comment: Your account (or a group that you belong to) needs at least to be assigned to the *Publisher* role in the folder you are trying to publish to. Check (or configure) the target folder (and Server!) in the project properties.

Comment: I finally figured out what solved the issue. Once I ran Visual Studio as Administrator the reports and data source deployed perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Visual Studio as Administrator.